# On Raspberry Pi, How to control PWM on GPIO18 using C++?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, gpio, pwm

Can anybody tell me how to use Raspberry Pi GPIO18 to produce PWM by using C++?

Comment: you could have found out my answer within a second with help of google. if you were asking for someone who codes this for you, you are in the wrong place. please try for yourself and provide your code here, and we will take a look into your code. this is not a codewriting-service

Answer (score 0):

Just throw a look at the [wiringPi library](http://wiringpi.com/).
It allows controlling the Pins of the RPi in an Arduino-like library (incl. PWM support)

Comment: I'm looking to use hardware PWM, but when I tried to use WiringPi library, I found it only provides software PWM. Is it right?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't looked through the code of the lib. If you want to use the low-level peripherals you can have a look in the datasheet of the RPi processor and [here](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15)